# AIOfile VS AIOfiles

Tags: python-asyncio

I want to open files from asynchronous processes and I've noticed two different modules that could be used: aiofiles and aiofile. However, I don't seem to find information about pros and cons between the two.

Would anyone have information about their main differences? Is either of them more widely use than the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

They are doing mostly the same things, currently the `aiofiles` lib supports a little bit more stuff than `aiofile` like temp files.

Currently the usage for `aiofile`:

- Downloads last month: 91,971 (pypistats.org)

and for `aiofiles`:

- Downloads last month: 4,732,892 (pypistats.org)

Personally, I would use the `aiofiles` because of the stats and the additional features.